# Build failed: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error

Tags: build, expo, fastlane

I try to upload my app via expo, and the build always fails at the "Run fastlane" step with an unknown error.

it gives the error:

> Refer to the "Xcode logs" (https://expo.dev/accounts/top10/projects/TOP10/builds/e09871a8-3d84-4bc4-b1c1-5d3114fe0c51#xcode-logs) phase for additional, more detailed logs

But I don't have Xcode, I have a Samsung-computer...

I tried to google it and found some things avout the app.json files and so, implemented some of them but still does not work :(

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?